# string to integer function in python

Tags: python, string, integer, type-conversion

I want to be able to change a list of distances from miles to kms, where the list of miles is obtained in the below bit of code:

```
input_string = input("Enter a list of distances, separated by spaces").strip()
```

To change the list of inputs into a list of integers, I used:

```
distances = input_string.split()
print("This is what you entered: ")
for distance in distances:
     print(distance)

def str2int(word):
    """Converts the list of string of miles into a list of integers of miles"""
    integer = int(word)
    if int(word):
        return integer
    else:
        sys.exit("Please try again and enter a list of integers.")


def validate_all(distances):
    """
    Checks if all the inputs are integers. If not all are integers, sys.exit
    without converting any of the distances and ask to try again.
    """

    true_list = []

    for distance in distances:
        if str2int(distance):
            true_list.append(distance)

    if len(distances) == len(true_list):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print("And now, we are going to convert the first one to kilometers:")
miles = distances[0]

if validate_all:
    # now, the calculation and display
    kms = miles_int * KMPERMILE
    print("The first distance you entered, in kilometers:", kms)

    for i in range(1, len(distances), 1):
        miles_int = str2int(distances[i])
        kms = miles_int * KMPERMILE
        print("The next distance you entered in kilometres:", kms)
```

BUT, when I try to check if all elements of the list of strings are able to be changed into an integer (with validate_all(word)) and have something like

```
12 23 apples banana 5
```

as my input, the program crashes saying that there is a value error at

```
str2int(word)
-> if int(word):
```

instead of me getting the sys.exit

Can anyone debug this for me/get this right for me please?

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> t = '12 23 apples banana 5'
>>> [int(x) for x in t.split() if x.isdecimal()]
[12, 23, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `try-except` clause:

```
def str2int(word):
    """Converts the list of string of miles into a list of integers of miles"""
    try:
        integer = int(word)
        return integer
    except ValueError:
        print "here"
        sys.exit("Please try again and enter a list of integers.")

print(str2int("asd"))
```

**Output:**

```
here
Please try again and enter a list of integers.
```

**Note:**

You can read more about Handling Exceptions and the `try-except` clauses in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

You tried doing `if int(x): ...`, but `int` is not a predicate.  If `x` is a string which cannot be converted to an int, a `ValueError` is raised. If `x='0'` for example, `if int(x): ...` is evaluated to `False`, despite being an int-like value.

What you need is the following predicate:

```
def is_int_able(x):
  try:
     int(x)
     return True
  except ValueError:
     return False
```

With this, you can do:

```
[ int(x) for x in line.split() if is_int_able(x) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `validate_all()` *could* make use of [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and [`str.digit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
In [1]: all(e.isdigit() for e in ['12', '23', 'apples', 'banana', '5'])
Out[1]: False

In [2]: all(e.isdigit() for e in ['12', '23', '5'])
Out[2]: True
```

But perhaps a better way would be to do away with this validation and employ the `if` filtering in a list comprehension:

```
In [3]: distances = ['12', '23', 'apples', 'banana', '5']

In [4]: [int(km) * km_to_miles for km in distances if km.isdigit()]
Out[4]: [7.456454304, 14.291537416, 3.10685596]
```